# How to store data fetched from MongoDB in a local array [MEAN]

Tags: angular

I'm working on a small MEAN application. I've stored some user details on mongodb. I just want to fetch them and store them in a local array (actually the email id only). Fetching part I've done and it is working perfectly but I'm not able to save it correctly. Here's my code.

**api.js**

```
router.get('/allregisteredusers', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error retrieving users");
    }
    else {
      res.json(user);
      console.log("Users: " + user); // OUTPUT IS CORRECT
    }
  });
});
```

The data is this:

[image]

Here's my service **user.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private _usersUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/allregisteredusers";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    console.log("getUsers called");
    return this.http.get<any>(this._usersUrl)
  }
}
```

Up till here everything is working perfectly. The problem starts now:
**userlist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  registerUserType ={
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    userid: ""
  };

  users: []; // In this array I want to store Email ids of all users

  constructor(..., private _userService: UserService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("Res: "+res); // Output:  Res: [object Object],[object Object]
        this.users = res.email
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
    console.log("List of all users: "+this.users); Output:// List of all users: undefined
  }
}
```

I gently remind hereby that api code is correct as I've checked on Postman also. Please correct my mistake. Why I'm not able to store it. I just want the Email of the user not the entire thing. Please help.

Comment: Please use the `push` method to push user-email and for all users emails you have to iterate all users. and push `email` on each iteration into the `user` array.

Comment: @R.Richards. I'm looking into it right now. Will get back to you.

Comment: @R. Richards. It worked for me. I got my answer with explanation. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is when trying to write out the value of users since getUsers returns an observable containing an asnyc function only in the .subscribe method you will get the result. Modify the onInit function this way you will get the result.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log("Res: "+res); // Output:  Res: [object Object],[object Object]
        this.users = res //array doesnt have a .email property
        console.log("List of all users: "+this.users);  here you will get the users list
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work :-( Still undefined

Comment: I just saw that the api response contians and array and since an array doesnt have email proeprty it will be undefined. this.users = res

Comment: Actually first I tried `this.users=res` only. But that was also not working. Thanks for your efforts. :-)